# parsing JSON with Telegraf

Tags: json, parsing, telegraf

I newbe about Influx 2.0 and Telegraf and i'm tryng to parse my sensor data with this file.conf :

```
[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]

  urls = ["http://127.0.0.1:8086"`]
  token = ""
  organization = ""
  bucket = ""


[[inputs.http]]
 
  name_override = "mysensor"
  username = "xxxxxxx"
  password = "xxxxxxx"
  urls = [
    "http://mon.mysensors.it/sensor.php",

  ]

  insecure_skip_verify = true
  method = "GET"
  timeout = "5s"
  data_format = "json"
```

Here the .php page :

```
{
"getdata":"S",
"datetime":"16-05-2022 17:58:05",
"temp_sitoa":"20.7 C",
"temp_sitoa_state":"OK",
"temp_sitob":"24.1 C",
"temp_sitob_state":"WARNING",
"hum_sitob":"33%",
"hum_sitob_state":"OK",
"temp_sitoi":"19.9 C",
"temp_sitoi_state":"OK"
}
```

How can I get the the value of "temp_sitob" ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `json_string_fields` option of the [json parser](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/parsers/json).

For a valid metric, you need to have one field and fields cannot be strings. If you look at your data, everything is a string. That is why no metrics are created. If you specify, however, using the `json_string_fields` option a string to use as a field, you can get data. I am using the `file` input to demonstrate this:

```ini
[[inputs.file]]
  files = ["data.json"]
  data_format = "json"
  json_string_fields = ["temp_sitob"]
```

```s
file temp_sitob="24.1 C" 1653506475000000000
```

Ideally, your data will have some numerical data in it to more easily graph and chart in InfluxDB. You could also use the various [processors](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/processors) in telegraf to convert the data types as well!

Hope that helps!